# How to change the value of a element inside a know row <tr> jquery?

Tags: jquery

I a trying to Change the value of a specific  inside a row specific  in my dinamic table. My Problem is that, is always doing the change only the first row  because of the dinamic Status of my table.

Here an example:

```
var tds = '<tr id="tr">';
tds += '<td><input type="text" id="id1" value="" size="3"></td>';
tds += '<td id="id2"></td>';
tds += '<td id="id3"></td>';

tds += '</tr>';
$("#table").append(tds);
```

Here for example I will like to Change the value of  in row 2 or second Iteration of the table. Can somebody give an idea?
Thanks

Comment: How are you changing the value? Can you post some `html` too or problem **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)** will be good to understand!

Comment: is this the full code or do have some ?

Comment: What event you want, `click','hover'`,or....

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using same ID name for multiple element, then it will returned for the first matched element only. In this case, i don't know what event you want to listen either `click` or whatever, if you know already which row to edit, here is the example solution :

Using [**nth-child**](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector

```
// will select second row
// and find the input
// then change it value into "HELLOO"
// nth-child start with 1(index)
// 1 = 1st row
// 2 = 2nd row
$('#table tr:nth-child(2)').find('input').val('HELLOO');
```

Using [**eq**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function

```
// will select second row
// and find the input
// then change it value into "HELLOO"
// eq is a zero-based index
// 0 = 1st row
// 1 = 2nd row
$('#table tr').eq(1).find('input').val('HELLOO');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your example just only has one row. If you mean to insert to second column you should do it this way:

```
$("#table>tr>td:nth-child(2)").html('something you want');
```

or

```
$("#table>tr>td:nth-child(2)").text('something you want');
```

if you really means second row do this:

```
var html ='<tr>' ;
html += '<td><input type="text" id="id2" value="" size="3"></td>';
html += '<td id="id2"></td>';
html += '<td id="id3"></td>';
html += '</tr>';

$( html ).insertAfter( $("#table>tr:nth-child(1)" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try 
`var tds = '<td><input type="text" id="id1" value="" size="3"</td>';
 tds += '<td id="id2"></td>';
 tds += '<td id="id3"></td>';
 $('#table tr:nth-child(2)').html(tds);`

This will replace your complete second row

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found the answer for my question and I will like to share it. Was very simple

```
$('table tr').last().find('td').eq(0).find('input').val("Wie schön!");
```